# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'branch')

Tags: angularjs, angular, localstorage

Boa tarde pessoal, sou novo na comunidade e estou precisando de uma ajuda.
Estou criando um dashboard de uma aplicação em Angular e sempre que tento acessar esse dashboard, aparece a mensagem abaixo:

```js
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'branch')
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'branch')
```

O metodo no Service está assim:

```js
  getUserData() {
    let users = window.localStorage.getItem('users');
    let jsonUsers = JSON.parse(users!)
    console.log("data: ", JSON.parse(jsonUsers.branch.id ));

    return jsonUsers.branch.id;

 }
```

Minhas interfaces :

```js
export interface Users {
    id: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName:string;
    email:string;
    username:string;
    branch:Branch[];
    roles:string;
    securityGroups:string;
}


export interface Branch {
    company:Company[];
    id :string;
    name:string;
}
```

O que pode está ocorrendo? Desculpa se estiver faltando mais coisas para colocar na duvida, qualquer coisa adiciono se precisar.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

O erro ***TypeError: Cannot read properties of null** é um erro comum em JavaScript que ocorre quando você tenta acessar uma propriedade de um objeto que é nulo ou indefinido. Isso significa que o objeto não foi inicializado corretamente ou foi definido como null em algum momento do código.

Por exemplo, em vez de simplesmente acessar a propriedade "branch" em uma variável que pode ser null, você pode verificar primeiro se ela é nula, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
 getUserData() {
    let users = window.localStorage.getItem('users');
    if(users != null && users != undefined){
      return;
    }
    let jsonUsers = JSON.parse(users);
    console.log("data: ", JSON.parse(jsonUsers.branch.id ));

    return jsonUsers.branch.id;

 }
```

ou simplemente usar o [**Optional chaining (?.)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) que retornara undefined ao inves de gerar o erro. como no exemplo abaixo:

```
 getUserData() {
    let users = window.localStorage.getItem('users');
    
    let jsonUsers = JSON.parse(users);
    console.log("data: ", JSON.parse(jsonUsers?.branch?.id ));

    return jsonUsers?.branch?.id;

 }
```

Answer (score -3):

Como já responderam, apenas mudar de `jsonUsers.branch.id` para `jsonUsers?.branch?.id` já resolve.

[Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)